# Criteria API combine 2 entties

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I'm trying to filter data with @OneToOne relationship between Account and Entry Entities.
What I need to do is search for Entry-s that have Account.glcode = "15"

here is what I have done but it is not working.

```
Root<?> root = mainQuery.from(Entry.class);
Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
Join<Entry,Account> entries = root.join("account");
predicate = builder.and((builder.equal(entries.get("glCode"),"15" )));
```

My Entry class

```
@Entity
public class Entry {

@Id
private Long id;
.........

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
private Account account;
```

This is Account class

```
@Entity
public class Account {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private Long glCode;
```

can Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATED**

```
  public PaginationResult getFilteredData(List<FilterConstraint> filters, Object classname) {
    try {
        CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<?> mainQuery = builder.createQuery(classname.getClass());
        Root<?> root = mainQuery.from(GLJournalEntry.class);
        Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();

        Predicate enumPredicate = builder.conjunction();
        Predicate today = builder.conjunction();
        Predicate on = builder.conjunction();

        for (FilterConstraint constraint : filters) {

            //IT is hard coded right now for testing purpose but should be customized for the future 
            if(constraint.getField().getValue().contains("-")){
                String[] items = constraint.getField().getValue().split("-");
                Join<GLJournalEntry,GLAccount> entries = root.join("glAccount");
                predicate = builder.and((builder.equal(entries.get("glCode"), constraint.getValues().getValue())));
                entries.getAttribute().toString();
                break;
            }

            switch (constraint.getOperator()) {
                case AFTER:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case BEFORE:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case BETWEEN:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.DATE) {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getStartDate(), constraint.getValues().getEndDate()));
                    } else if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.INTEGER) {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), Integer.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getMinValue()), Integer.valueOf(constraint.getValues().getMaxValue())));
                    } else {
                        predicate = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getMinValue(), constraint.getValues().getMaxValue()));
                    }
                    break;
                case EMPTY:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.isEmpty(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                    break;
                case EQUALS:
                    if (constraint.getField().getType() == FieldDataType.ENUM) {

                        Object enumV = null;

                        if (constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().size() > 1) {

                            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (EnumValue enumValue : constraint.getValues().getEnumValue()) {


                                for (Field f : classname.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                                    if (f.getName().equals(constraint.getField().getValue())) {
                                        System.out.println("T");
                                        Class<?> clz = f.getType();
                                        Object[] consts = clz.getEnumConstants();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < consts.length - 1; i++) {
                                            if (consts[i].toString().equals(enumValue.getValue())) {
                                                enumV = consts[i];
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), enumV));
                            }

                            enumPredicate = builder.and(builder.or(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{})));
                            break;
                        }

                        for (Field f : classname.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                            if (f.getName().equals(constraint.getField().getValue())) {
                                System.out.println("T");
                                Class<?> clz = f.getType();
                                Object[] consts = clz.getEnumConstants();
                                for (int i = 0; i < consts.length - 1; i++) {
                                    if (consts[i].toString().equals(constraint.getValues().getEnumValue().get(0).getValue())) {
                                        enumV = consts[i];
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }


                        enumPredicate = builder.equal(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), enumV);
                        break;
                    }
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.equal(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    break;
                case LESS_THAN:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.lessThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    break;

                case MORE_THAN:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.greaterThan(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), constraint.getValues().getValue()));
                    break;
                case NOT_EMPTY:
                    predicate = builder.and(builder.isNotEmpty(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue())));
                    break;
                case ON:
                    on = builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), DateUtils.getFirstSecondOfDate(constraint.getValues().getStartDate()), DateUtils.getLastSecondOfDate(constraint.getValues().getStartDate()));
                    break;
                case STARTS_WITH:

                case TODAY:
                    today = builder.and(builder.between(root.get(constraint.getField().getValue()), DateUtils.getFirstSecondOfDate(new Date()), DateUtils.getLastSecondOfDate(new Date())));
                    break;
            }


        }


        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        cq.select(builder.count(cq.from(classname.getClass())));
        em.createQuery(cq);
        cq.where(predicate, enumPredicate, today, on);
        Long count = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();

        mainQuery.where(predicate, enumPredicate, today, on);


        //Count for pagination
        TypedQuery<?> q = em.createQuery(mainQuery);
        q.setMaxResults(filters.get(0).getCount());
        int firstResult = filters.get(0).getPage() * filters.get(0).getCount() - filters.get(0).getCount();
        q.setFirstResult(firstResult);


        PaginationResult result = new PaginationResult();
        result.setData((List<Client>) q.getResultList());
        result.setMaxResults(count);

        System.out.println(result.getData().size());

        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter for glCode is a String, but must be a long. And use better ParameterExpression,

Example:

```
public List<Entry> findEntryByGlCode(Long glCode) {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    final CriteriaQuery<Entry> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Entry.class);
    final Root<Entry> root = query.from(Entry.class);

    Join<Entry, Account> join = root.join("account");
    ParameterExpression<Long> glcodeParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Long.class, "glCode");
    Predicate equal = criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("glCode"), glcodeParameter);

    query.where(equal);
    query.select(root);

    return entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("glCode", glCode).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: it throws an error: could not resolve property: glCode of: ge.shemo.model.accounting.glAccount.Entry

Comment: Your classes have getter/setter?

Comment: Post your complete method please.

Comment: I have added the full method. I pasted your code at the beginning with comment - 'IT is hard coded right now '

Comment: Your method is very big.  Your last error said ge.shemo.model.accounting.glAccount.Entry.getGlCode() not found, but you post Entry -> Account -> glCode. Your fault isn't more the the query.

Comment: I used your code and it works after some modifications. But there is a problem with count query. How can I get count of rows  for pagination in such case?